# Application works without installation

Tags: vb.net, installation, exe, advanced-installer

I created a program in vb.net in vb language. After that I created an installer (.msi) for the same in Advanced Installer program. I installed it on the computer and everything seems professional.

I copied the folder that contains the program and all its dependees and sent to to a different computer. I was surprised that the application (.exe) file works without installation!!

How can I make my application works only with installation?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: That's a very debatable goal. Why would you want that? After all, there are several programs that explicitly try to be portable.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Well, I put a lot of effort on this program. I am gonna install it on my colleages computers at work through IT department (IT will only have the installer file). However, I dont want my colleagues to share it with other people outside the company without my consent  by copying the program folder and sending it.

Comment: Installation is only required if you have to include stuff that is not, or can not, be in your application folder. Otherwise pretty much all applications work stand-alone.

Comment: But the simple way to reach your goal is to make the installer put a file somewhere on the hard drive, and then make your application check if that file exists every time you start it. If it doesn't exist show a MessageBox, close it, crash it or whatever you like. :)

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Installer has a [licensing module that works for VB.NET](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-licensing.html) apps too, which you can easily integrate into your installer.

However, this is in the Enterprise edition, and I assume you are using the free edition, as this sounds like quite a simple application/installer.

In this case you can try looking for an alternative OSS solution for a licensing/trial library.

Basically with this library every user that needs to use the software will need a key to activate it, so even if they copy the folder with the application files from Programs Folder, they will still not be able to run your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using a free version and I dont have these options :(

I am not really an expert, so could u please elaborate more about OSS solution? or if there is a previous post that I can refer to?

An smiple idea came to my mind while taking a shower. I can get the name of the PC of the people I want to install the application to and make my application check the name before it starts. I know it is simple.

Anyway, I really want to learn more about your idea. It is more professional.